# HowTo - Grid with a variable num of rows per column

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I need to use a control to list meetings that will happen in the current week, vertically (On a WinForms application, VS2010).

The user painted what he would like to see (these "Add" elements are buttons that will add a Meeting to its cell, while the the button itself moves to the next row).
[image]

I was thinking on using a datagridview for this. Should I?
Can i define that a specific cell will be a button (instead of the entire column, as it happens with the DataGridViewButtonColumn)?

Thks

Comment: Does everything in a row occur at the same time, but on a different day of the week?  Or is this simply a variable number of meetings per day?

Comment: One possibility is a UserControl that can be re-used for each day of the week.  It could have a FlowLayoutPanel within it to display the variable number of meetings and have the Button at the bottom.  You'd display those UserControls in a TableLayoutPanel that has a fixed number of columns (5 or 7) for a week.

Comment: Nice Exercise. [this](http://pastebin.com/Zp0rMdqS) is my attempt at it. 12 minutes total development time. 35 lines of  XAML + 50 lines of C# code (including empty spaces/curly braces). Totally resolution independent. Vector based, hardware accelerated (no flicker). DataBinding-based, UI is decoupled from Data. Data can be passed directly to an underlying database / web service / whatever. Might be integrated in an existing winforms application using an [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Oh, I forgot, [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/HtNEbRu.png).

Comment: XAML replies to WinForms posts are truly useless

Comment: I don't think you can change the type on different rows  - maybe... All the work can be done with text cells and you can use the Cell events to react to the clicks.

Comment: @HighCore, thank you very much! I am not used to work with WPF and cannot spare time now for investigation, but I will look at your solution later because it seems very interesting.

Comment: Found that it is possible to transform specific cells into buttons:

DataGridView1.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(ColIndex) = New DataGridViewButtonCell()
DataGridView1.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(ColIndex).Value = "<Add>"
I will code the behaviour directly on the datagridview, using styles and this ButtonCell class.